# How do I go about displaying data that looks like its on an 8.5x11 paper

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display a tabular data that should look like its on an 8.5x11 paper. What I do is I create an 8.5x11 div and put borders and white background to make it look like a paper. And then I need to determine how many pages I need so I can render those many divs. I can get the total height of the elements so I can use that as basis if content has already reached the limit of a single page but my problem is I don't know how to render the next divs after the first one.

I can only get the height during render:

```
<div>
{
    <div className="content">
        <table id="main-tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student No.</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    this.state.registeredStudents.map((stud) => {
                        currentTotalHeight += $("#main-tbl")[0].offsetHeight;
                        console.log(currentTotalHeight);
                        return (
                            currentTotalHeight < this.contentHeightLimit &&
                            <tr key={stud.id} data-id={stud.id}>
                                <td>{stud.studentNo}</td>
                                <td>{stud.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{stud.lastName}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

I was planning ong checking the height of the table eveytime an element is added and once it reaches the supposed page height, start new div again, but that's my problem, I don't know how to render the next div. How do I structure this so that once I reach the height limit, render the same div again? I want to do something like:

```
<div>
{
    this.state.numOfPages.map((index) => {
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <table id="main-tbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Student No.</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.registeredStudents.map((stud) => {
                            currentTotalHeight += $("#main-tbl")[0].offsetHeight;
                            console.log(currentTotalHeight);
                            return (
                                currentTotalHeight < this.contentHeightLimit &&
                                <tr key={stud.id} data-id={stud.id}>
                                    <td>{stud.studentNo}</td>
                                    <td>{stud.firstName}</td>
                                    <td>{stud.lastName}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    })
}
</div>
```

But I don't know how to get the no. of pages until everything is rendered by which it'll be too late.

[image]

Comment: can you make a painted image from what you exactly expected to display?

Comment: @b3hr4d I added an image on how it currently looks. The white rectangle is the div that's the 8.5x11 paper, and as you can see, there's data exceeding the length, that's my problem. I need to render a new div to indicate its the next page but I can't get the supposed total number of pages without rendering the actual content so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Screen pixels *(apparent size)* have nothing to do with a printed page size. Use `@media print`, keeping your 8.5/11 aspect ratio in mind.

Comment: @StackSlave this isn't for printing, I just need to make it on a UI that looks like a paper

Comment: 8.5/11 * elementHeight = correctAspeclElementWidth ... 11/8.5 * elementWidth = correctAspectElementHeight... so you probably want  the second equation. I would have `width:100%` on the page and use `11/8.5 * Element.getBoundingClientRect().width`. You'll want to use  `addEventListener('reszie', function(){})` as well, so you can refactor, based on `Element.getBoundingClientRect().width`.

Comment: Ok got it. I'll make you an example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way to do that, by splitting the array of items into an array of the array then loop them into the table.

If you want more logic for calculating height you can make a function for getting the number of `itemOnPage` then split items with that.

```js
const App = () => {
  const items = Array.from(Array(70)).map((_, v) => ({no:v,firstName:"name"+v,lastName:"last"+v}))
  const itemOnPage = 24;
  const arrayOfArrays = [];
  for (let i=0; i < items.length; i+=itemOnPage) {
       arrayOfArrays.push(items.slice(i,i+itemOnPage));
  }
  return(
    <div style={styles.root}>
     {arrayOfArrays.map((items, v) => (
      <div style={styles.paper}>
        <p style={styles.pageNum}>{v+1}</p>
        <table key={v}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Student No.</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(row => (
              <tr key={row.no} data-id={row.no}>
                  <td>{row.no}</td>
                  <td>{row.firstName}</td>
                  <td>{row.lastName}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
     ))}
    </div>
    )
};
const styles={
  root:{
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    height:1800,
    display:"flex",
    flexDirection:"column",
  },
  paper:{
    position:"relative",
    margin:10,
    padding: 5,
    border:"1px solid",
    width: "425px",
    height: "550px",
    backgroundColor: "white"

  },
    pageNum :{
    position:"absolute",
    bottom:0,
    right:20
  },
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```